# border-radius not working

Tags: css, border

I'm working on a basic `div` and for some peculiar reason, `border-radius: 7px` isn't applying to it.

```
.panel {
  float: right;
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px; // not working
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you can apply border-radius to a wrapper container and it will work nicely. For example, I was trying to set border-radius to a div inside of <a> tag and it was not working. But when I applied border-radius to <a> tag directly it worked like a charm.

Comment: i was having the same problem, i solved it like this, in my case removing ".btn" class solved my problem as i was using bootsrap.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

To whomever may have this issue. My problem was border-collapse. It was set to:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

I set it to:

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

and it fixed the issue.

Comment: I just added "border-collapse: separate;" to my in-line CSS and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the late update to this post. After reading the border-collapse spec on W3C can confirm this is semantically the correct answer and appears to have decent cross browser compatibility

Comment: When I set border collapse to separate it REMOVED ALL BORDERS from all <tr> elements.

Comment: I have had issues similar in the past because of other CSS that shouldn't have been set, then correcting one showed the error in the other. If you create a codepen or something it would be easier to see what might be the issue.

Comment: doesnt work properly. separate makes different view of table with spaces between row and columnsm which is innopropriate

Answer (score 75):

For anyone who comes across this issue in the future, I had to add

```
perspective: 1px;
```

to the element that I was applying the border radius to. Final working code:

```
.ele-with-border-radius {
    border-radius: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1px;
}
```

Editing my answer to include some clarification from others: **Typically all you need is `overflow: hidden;`** In my case, that wasn't working either and I needed to add `perspective: 1px;`. I think this might have been caused by 3D CSS Transforms that I applied to the element with border radius.

Comment: The `overflow: hidden` property does the job for most of the containers.

Comment: overflow: hidden, FTW

Comment: perspective?? Well *that's* weird!

Comment: I'd love for someone to explain why this worked for me. 99.999% of times you only need overflow:hidden on the container, but sometimes that simply doesn't work. It's very odd.

Comment: I tried the above border collapse but that didn't work  - but these (overflow and perspective) got it working for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 57):

To add a bit on to @ethanmay 's answer: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44334424/8479303)...

If there are **contents within the div** that has the curved corners, you have to set `overflow: hidden` because otherwise the child  div's overflow can give the impression that the `border-radius` isn't working.

```
<!-- This will look like the border-radius isn't working-->
<div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px;">
  <div style="background: red;">
      text!
  </div>
</div>

<!-- but here the contents properly fit within the rounded div -->
<div style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="background: red;">
      text!
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/o2t68exj/

Comment: This answer worked for me. None of the other's did. Specifically I was working with nested <ul> and <li> tags.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on my answer! :)

Answer (score 40):

Im just highlighting part of @Ethan May answer which is

```
overflow: hidden;
```

It would most probably do the work for your case.

Answer (score 12):

if you have parent element than your parent element must have overflow: hidden; property
because if your children content is getting oveflowed from parent border than your border will be visible .otherwise your borderradius is working but it is hide by your children content.

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.inner1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FF9933,white, green);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1">
     
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

For some reason your padding: 7px setting is nullifying the border-radius. Change it to `padding: 0px 7px`

Comment: Thank you. It was that the box applied border-radius successfully, but because of padding, it couldn't be seen.

Answer (score 8):

Try add **!important** to your css. Its working for me.

```
.panel {
  float: right;
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 7px!important;
}
```

Comment: My problem was that somewhere else had the !important so it was stepping on my properties

Answer (score 7):

in your div class="social-box"  css

use

```
            float:right
```

instead of

```
             float:left
```

Comment: Why? This is unrelated to the question asked.

Comment: border-radius was successfully applying on that div but it was not float correctly..

Comment: This doesn't fix it on Chrome.

Comment: @Alex..i dn't know what version of chrome you are using..but it works fine for me on Chrome 19.0.1084.56, FF 13.0

Comment: I've tried to set `float: initial` in the browser, which solved my problem.  

Then I've noticed, that after removing that property it works as well, I think in my case the problem in the browser: **Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)**

Answer (score 3):

Now I am using the browser kit like this:

```
{
border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't sort out this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is unrelated to how you have set `border-radius`. Fire up Chrome and hit `Ctrl+Shift+j` and inspect the element. Uncheck `width` and the border will have curved corners.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I have a dropdown list in my div container, so I can not use `overflow: hidden` or my dropdown list will be hidden.

Inspired by this discussion: https://twitter.com/siddharthkp/status/1094821277452234752
I use `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` in the child element to fix this issue.

> make sure you add it the correct value for each child separately

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, with a `position: absolute` container cutting dropdowns because of an `overflow: hidden` needed by my container to have a working `border-radius`. I removed the `overflow: hidden` and applied a selective border radius on each corner elements as suggested. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

you may include bootstrap to your html file and you put it under the style file so if you do that bootstrap file will override the style file briefly like this

```
     // style file
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
     // bootstrap file
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

the right way is this

```
    // bootstrap file
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    // style file
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Including Bootstrap is not a valid answer. You're suggesting users fix this issue by adding a 34kb resource that users need to download.

Comment: @Matt I think he meant that if you would use bootstrap, it could probably not work because your styles get overwritten by bootstrap, because of importing order

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `display: block` in my case to make it work, the essential part being that the display must not be inlined; so the element had the following:

```css
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
```

(note: it also works with `display: block`)

See for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow